# iOS Swift Filter Array using NSPredicate crashing on run time

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I have a cell Model

```
struct BeerCellModel: Hashable {

    var beer: Beer

    static func == (lhs: BeerCellModel, rhs: BeerCellModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.beer.id == rhs.beer.id
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return self.beer.id
    }
}
```

AND

```
public struct Beer {
    public var abv: String
    public var ibu: String
    public var id: Int
    public var name: String
    public var style: String
    public var ounces: Int
}
```

Now i have a array name '**items = [BeerCellModel]**' of above cell model and i'm filtering array with param `style`

```
let value = ["tuborg", "budwiser", "bira"]
let query = value.map { "SELF.beer.style CONTAINS[cd] \($0)" }.joined(separator: " || ")
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: query)
let results = self.items.filter { predicate.evaluate(with: $0) }
```

But i'm getting run time crash

> 2018-08-08 00:38:01.787170+0530 BeerCrafts[3388:401950] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[<_SwiftValue 0x60400064dce0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key beer.'

What is wrong in array or predicate?

Update: Adding JSON response of `Beer`

```
  {
    "abv": "0.08",
    "ibu": "35",
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Monks Blood",
    "style": "Belgian Dark Ale",
    "ounces": 12
  },
  {
    "abv": "0.07",
    "ibu": "65",
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Brew Free! or Die IPA",
    "style": "American IPA",
    "ounces": 12
  },
  {
    "abv": "0.04",
    "ibu": "17",
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Hell or High Watermelon Wheat",
    "style": "Fruit / Vegetable Beer",
    "ounces": 12
  }
```

Comment: @AhmadF: The expected result should give items in which style matches  in value array

Comment: You probably mean simply `NSPredicate(format: "beer.style IN %@", value)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point, there is no need to deal with `NSPredicate`, the `filter` method is sufficient enough for your case, as:

```
let filtered = items.filter { value.contains($0.beer.style) }
```

The `filtered` is array of `BeerCellModel` which should contains the objects that their `beer.style` is one of the `value` array elements.

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
let value = ["tuborg", "budwiser", "bira"]
let query = value.map { "self CONTAINS[cd] '\($0)'" }.joined(separator: " || ")
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: query)
let results = self.items.filter { predicate.evaluate(with: $0.beer.style) }
```

Comment: Can you explain as well

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to map an array of `String`s, not an array of `BeerCellModel` structs.

Comment: Wrong i m adding predicate query in filter. Google it for references